# How to connect Blogger website with Google spreadsheet using Google App script?

Tags: google-sheets, blogger, google-sheets-api

I want to know if I can use Google spreadsheet as a back-end database for my Blogger website. I have done so in past using Google Fusion Tables.

I can use Web Apps as well by using a custom domain to direct to their long URL. But when I update the script, I have to deploy the web app. This changes the long URL, so I need to update my redirection.

Is there a way to access & update a Google Spreadsheet from my website.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with Blogger.

However, you can do this with Sites.

If you setup a spreadsheet like this:

[image: Sheets setup]

Then you create a web app from that like this:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl("YOUR URL").getSheetByName("LinkConfig");
function getDataIndex(key) {
  var Keys = sheet.getRange(2, 1, sheet.getMaxColumns(), 1).getValues().map(function(row) {return row[0]});
  for (var i=0; i<Keys.length; i++) {
    if (Keys[i]==key) return i+2;
  }
}

function getData(key) {
  return sheet.getRange(getDataIndex(key), 2).getValue();
}


function test() {
  Logger.log(getData("url1"));
  Logger.log(getData("url2"));
}

function webApp(key) {
  //Get contents from target URL
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(getData(key)).getContentText();
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(content); //Returns new page with the same content
}

function doGet(e) {
  if (e.parameter.key != null && e.parameter.key != undefined) {
    return webApp(e.parameter.key);
  } else {
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput("<h1>Error! You didn't specify a 'key' parameter</h1>");
  }
}
```

And deploy it.

Now, as long as you don't change that one URL (meaning you don't edit this main "config" webapp, you are able to change values on the spreadsheet and access the pages linked there by passing the key.

To use it in Sites, add an Embed element and set the URL to : *yourwebappurl*?key=*keyvalue*

[image: Adding as embedded]

Comment: This is a Good integration way and Data can appear as a widget embedded in the HTML. But Google Sites does not provide HTML editing. I wonder if we have GET and POST request as we used to have for Google Fusion Tables.

Comment: The request will be a GET by default.

Comment: Ya, you are right. Embedding is a good for displaying data. What I wish was to create a custom GET and POST query for storing and retrieving data e.g. the number of likes on an Image. I used to fetch data in JSON format with Custom Query on Google Fusion tables, but unfortunately they are discontinued.